# How To Control A Border In A Template, Like That?

Tags: html, css

[The Picture :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6oGx.png)

- Guys Anyone Know How To Make This Template Like That, I've Tried The Border in One Direction, But I Don't Know How To Control It To Be Like That?, "I'm Not Using JavaScript BTW", Also Never Mind About The Indentation.

```css
div {
                display: block;
                margin: 30px;
                width: 400px;
                background-color: rgb(179, 179, 179);
                padding: 20px;
            }

            .shape-1 {
                border-left: 7px solid rgb(250, 90, 90);
                
            }
```

```html
<div class="shape-1">This Is Importnat Note</div>
```

?

Comment: The Certain Purpose Of The Code Is In The Link :- (The Picture :)

Comment: what do you mean by "like that" do you mean the space around it? Use margin for that.

Comment: applying a padding to div should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Add any tags to text link `h1-h6` or `p` or `span` tag and add border left to tag not for div

```css
div {
                display: block;
                margin: 30px;
                width: 400px;
                background-color: rgb(179, 179, 179);
                padding: 20px;
            }

            span{
                border-left: 7px solid rgb(250, 90, 90);
                padding-left:5px;
            }
```

```html
<div class="shape-1"><span>This Is Importnat Note</span></div>
```